# Disallowing function to be called from Console in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Alright so I've a function (not exactly the one written bellow, that one is just an example)

```
function test() 
{
  alert("Hello");
}
```

Now the problem is that people are able to go into console and just type "test()" and call the function.

Is there a way to prevent this? I dont want of people to call functions from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow the context that your function is executed in, eg:

```js
(function() {
  function test() { /* Do anything */ }
  test();
  // Call test anywhere here
})()

test(); // Error: test is undefined
```